# Django Method Not Allowed Status 405 on a Ajax call to a foreign key model

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, django-views

**Intro:** I am making a stackoverflow style Question and Answer App, where a user can ask a question and other users can answer the question. Users Also have the option to Upvote and Downvote both questions and Answers. I am using Ajax calls to asynchronously update the upvote and downvote.

I was successful is  asynchronously upvote and downvote Questions. but somehow the same code is giving me a **Method Not Allowed Status 405** on the Answer upvote/downvote (*See Images below*)

> for convenience and keeping code small lets only talk about the answer upvote code

[image]
[image]

*I believe I may me doing something wrong in the URLs or in the calling URL function in the model*

**Models.py**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField()
    ansup = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='answer_ansup')
    ansdown = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='answer_ansdown')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('questions:single', kwargs={'username': self.question.user.username,
                                               'slug': self.question.slug})

    def get_ansup_url(self): #This is the 1 of 2 place I believe I may be doing something wrong
        return reverse('questions:ansup', kwargs={'username': self.author.username,
                                              'pk': self.pk})

    def get_ansdown_url(self):
        return reverse('questions:ansdown', kwargs={'username': self.author.username,
                                                'pk': self.pk})
```

**Below are the views.py**

```
class AnswerAnsupToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Answer, pk=pk)
        user = self.request.user
        context = {"answer": obj}

        if user in obj.ansup.all():
            obj.ansup.remove(user)
        else:
            obj.ansup.add(user)

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string("questions/answer_upvote_section.html", context, request=self.request)
            return JsonResponse({"form": html})

        url = obj.get_absolute_url()
        print(url)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

**Below are the templates**

> Please note that the templates for the Answer model are a bit complicated. Each Question is in its own Page.(Question DetailView) However All the answers to that Question also are on the same page. Answers don't have a detail view The variable `answer` comes from the forloop as you can see below. Putting the Script in the forloop messes up the code real bad. Meaning you press upvote once it runs multiple times. Plus it doesn't even correspond to the same answer at times.

```
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}
   {% if user in answer.ansup.all %}
    <form action="{% url 'questions:ansup' username=answer.author.username pk=answer.pk %}" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left:-13px;" name="answer_pk" value="{{ answer.pk }}"
            class="btn btn-link ans_upvote_button">
            <img src="{% static 'images/Upvote.png' %}" height="25px">
        </button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form action="{% url 'questions:ansup' username=answer.author.username pk=answer.pk %}" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left:-13px;" name="answer_pk" value="{{ answer.pk }}"
            class="btn btn-link ans_upvote_button">
            <img src="{% static 'images/Upvote_blank.png' %}" height="25px">
        </button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

**Below are the urls.py** *This is on the 2nd places I have doubts I may be doing something wrong*

> Detailview of the Question/Answer page

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

> Answer Upvote Url

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/ansup/$', views.AnswerAnsupToggle.as_view(), name='ansup'),
```

**Below is the JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', ".ans_upvote_button", function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
            var pk = $(this).attr("value");
            var upvote = $("#answer_upvote_section");
            $.ajax({
                url : "{{answer.get_ansup_url}}", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "pk": pk,
                    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    upvote.html(data["form"]);
                }, error: function (rs, e) {
                    console.log(rs, e);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try `url: {% url 'question:ansup' answer.auther.username answer.pk %}` to check if `get_ansup_url()` is working correctly.

Comment: Check in your browser developer tools the source code, to see if the `url: "{{ answer.get_ansup_url }}"` resolved to the correct URL.

Comment: @dirkgroten That's the same URL I have in my JS

Comment: ah that's the problem then: If your js is not inside your template (.html), then how do you expect `{{ answer.get_ansup_url }}` to be resolved by Django? Template variables like `{{ answer.get_ansup_url }}` and `{{ csrf_token }}` are replaced on the *back-end*, your script is running inside a user's browser on the *front-end*.

Comment: @dirkgroten I din't understand The JS is in base.html The question upvote/downvote is there too that works fine. Its just the answer upvote/downvote that seems to have a problem

Comment: If the js is inside base.html then you would not see `url: "{{ answer.get_ansup_url }}"` inside the browser developer console (view source), but `url: "/username/23/ansup/"`. I asked you what you see when you view source inside your browser and you said it's same as what you showed here. So that means you include your javascript using a separate file (`<script src="path/to/your/js/file"></script>`)

Comment: @dirkgroten Wow that was a good catch.. I'm sorry I din't understand what you meant the 1st time.  **I have attached the screenchot of `view source` or `f12` above** I am surprised to see that it is blank

Comment: That means probably `answer` isn’t defined in your template’s context. You don’t show the code for your original view (the one that renders the template extending base.html) so I can’t help further.

Comment: First: the view `AnswerAnsupToggle` has `{‘answer’: obj}` as context for a JsonResponse. That’s not what’s rendering base.html. Which view is rendering the page containing the js? Second: {{ answer.get_ansup_url}} is correct, as long as `answer` is defined. Third: you can’t mix javascript into your template tags because javascript runs in the browser, whereas template tags are evaluated on the server.

Comment: Your vote up button: in which template is it and which view renders that template? That’s where you need to put your javascript (not in base.html because all your templates extend base.html) and the view needs to pass `answer` to the template’s context

Comment: I am sorry it took me so long to understand. I know what the problem is now. The `question` variable has a `DetailView` so 1 page has only 1 question. But the answer page has no `DetailView` So far I accessed each answer through a `forloop` in the Question's `DetailView` template example **{% for answer in question.answers.all %}** thats how I got the `answer` variable Now that answer variable only exists in that forloop. So how do you think I should proceed from here. That is because each question can have multiple answers and they have to be on the same page